# Visual Studio is catching an error with my new Regex var

Tags: c#, regex

For some reason Visual Studio is catching an error on the var regexItem creation line.

> "} expected."

I thought I missed a closing "}" but I think it is something to do with creation of the Regex variable (first time I have tried to use Regex).

For context: I want to make sure that the user is only typing 0-9, commas, decimals, operations (+/*-), or equal symbols in the "problem" string.

Thanks for any and all help. Here is the code block:

```
    private static bool MainMenu()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter an equation to solve (use +, -, *, or /) or 'exit' to quit.");

        string problem = Console.ReadLine();

        if (problem.Equals("exit", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return false;
        }

        var regexItem = new Regex("^[0-9/*+,.-=]+$");

        else if (regexItem.IsMatch(problem))
        {
            Calculate(problem);
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your entry is invalid. Please only enter numbers and operations. :)");
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're declaring a new variable smack in the middle of an `if..else if..else` block.  You can't do that.

Comment: By "catching an error", you mean it won't compile, right?

Comment: The regex is wrong, `.-=` creates a range. Escape the hyphen or put at the end of the char class.

Comment: Thank you, Paul. That was what was throwing the error.

Comment: Removing `else` will not fix the issue with the regex pattern. Use `"^[0-9/*+,.=-]+$"`

Comment: @RobertPrine - In the future, please be precise: "Visual Studio is catching an error" is a vague statement, and is probably ignoring a more fundamental truth. Do you mean your program won't compile? Do you mean that when you run your program, an exception occurs? An exception would occur whether or not Visual Studio was present, so the mention of VS is specious. If you're getting an exception, why not tell us what it says? Folks are downvoting and voting to close your question because it is poorly written, and I agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
else if (regexItem.IsMatch(problem))
```

To

```
if (regexItem.IsMatch(problem))
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues you are having with the current solution:

- The "wild" `else` on the `else if (regexItem.IsMatch(problem))` line that should be deleted in order for the code to be compiled
- The regex contains a known issue when an unescaped hyphen creates a range in the character class. Use `"^[0-9/*+,.=-]+$"` where the hyphen is put at the end of the character class and does not have to be escaped. Or `@"^[0-9/*+,.\-=]+$"` (and no one will be able to spoil the pattern since adding more symbols should not ruin the pattern).